# how to write an xhr/ajax request in React on the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I have googled this and it tells me that I should use axios or something. I've used axios before and it's specifically for requests made on the client. What if in my application I have an express server where I have specific routes and then I want to send the response to my React client components or indeed make a request to my server from the client. how would I do that?

lets say Express server makes a get request to `/users` and I use `fetch` to get that data from the API. with that returned data I then want to send it to the client (React Components state)

I know I could just use `componentDidMount` and call `axios.get()` on the client side but I would like to make the request server side and then send it over to the client

Comment: `Axios` works for both client and server side. If you want to use `fetch`, you can use `isomorphic-fetch`.

Comment: @konekoya ok thanks. why is my request taking ages to complete though when I just do fetch(url) and then try and hit that route in my client side app, the chrome window hangs for 10 seconds and then times out, every time

Comment: You can use devTools for further investigation. Also, check your server log. If you're properly handling the request, it usually hangs there.

Comment: I can see the response in my server though but it's not getting sent to the client :(

Comment: Okay, then you can check the network panel in you Chrome devTools. And see the response header.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not using react but express if i get it correctly, so you can use axios from your server as well

Inside the route, make the axios call, store the response and return it to the client